# How to Display Element of Array that has specific value/character?

Tags: php, arrays, json

I Have A json Array  from  hxxp://best1st.info/Moviedb/json.php?m=tt2015381&o=json

Here is sample of the array output :

```
. and so on
.
. 
[STORYLINE] => On planet Earth in 1988, young Peter Quill ( ) sits in the waiting room of a hospital...
[ALSO_KNOWN_AS] => Array
    (
        [0] => Guardianes de la galaxia = Argentina
        [1] => Qalaktikanin MÃ¼hafizeÃ§ileri = Azerbaijan
        [2] => ÐŸÐ°Ð·Ð¸Ñ‚ÐµÐ»Ð¸Ñ‚Ðµ Ð½Ð° Ð“Ð°Ð»Ð°ÐºÑ‚Ð¸ÐºÐ°Ñ‚Ð° = Bulgaria (Bulgarian title)
        [3] => GuardiÃµes da GalÃ¡xia = Brazil
    )

[RELEASE_DATES] => Array
    (
.
.
. and so on
```

I want to check if in "**ALSO_KNOWN_AS**" Element, have "*Argentina*" word , If "ALSO_KNOWN_AS" Element have the "Argentina" word, then display it (the value).

I have try to do it (search with google and here on stackoverflow), but seem my code dont work, Can some one here help me to fix it , here is my code

```
$url   = 'http://best1st.info/Moviedb/json.php?m=tt2015381&o=json';
$newdata = json_decode(file_get_contents($url));

$alsoKnownAs = $newdata->ALSO_KNOWN_AS;

if (in_array('Argentina', $alsoKnownAs)) {
    echo "Match found";
    // echo the-array-value
}

else
{
echo "Match not found";
return false;
}
```

Thanks You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
$url   = 'http://best1st.info/Moviedb/json.php?m=tt2015381&o=json';
$newdata = json_decode(file_get_contents($url));
$found = false;

foreach($newdata->ALSO_KNOWN_AS as $value)
{
    if(strpos($value, "Argentina") !==false)
    {
        echo $value;
        echo "<br/>";
        $found = true;
    }   
}   

if($found===false)
{
    echo "Not found";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function searchArray($search, $array)
{
    foreach($array as $key => $value)
    {
        if (stristr($value, $search))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Here in the above function first argument is the string you like to search and  second argument is the array and it will iterate through entire array with the function `stristr` whose work is to return portion on found else false.

Note: if you need case sensitive search instead of `stristr` use `strstr` or `strchr`

```
if (searchArray('Argentina', $alsoKnownAs)) {
    echo "Match found";
    // echo the-array-value
}

else
{
echo "Match not found";
return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your entries in the `ALSO_KNOWN_AS` array are not single words like "Argentina" but rather comparisons with country names and other text. This is why `in_array()` won't find it. `in_array()` needs precise matches. So you have to check all items.

I suggest you replace the if statement by a foreach loop:

```
...
...
$found = false;
foreach ($alsoKnownAs as $item) {
   if (strpos($item, 'Argentina') !== false) {
      $found = true;
      break;
   }
}

if (!$found) {
  echo "Match not found";
  return false;
}
```

Hope this helps :-)

Comment: this give me "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'as' (T_AS), expecting ';' in D:\XAMPP\htdocs..." massage, but the above answer have solve my problem thaks q anyway peter_the_oak :)

Comment: Yes, it must be a `foreach` loop :-) I've corrected the answer.